# layout of the text

Tags: support, mathjax

I have been on stack exchange for months, but still haven't figured out how to start a new line. The usual Latex double slash or \newline doesn't seem to work here. Could anyone help?

Comment: Do you see the question-mark button at the top-right of the editor? It gives you menus and an ["advanced help"](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/editing-help) link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line breaks are easy: just leave a blank line between two paragraphs...

...like this. (Helpful tip: to see how any given post was formatted, click on the `edit` button to the left of the signature.)

You can also force line breaks by using the HTML tag `<br>`. However, I would strongly advise you not to abuse this and to 
 let the Stack Exchange Markdown compiler do its thing. Just write your paragraphs, separate them with a blank line, and you're good to go.

If you want a line break within a math block, then you need to use the `align` environment, where line breaks are implemented by the usual LaTeX double backslash:

```
$$
    \begin{align}
    a+b & =c \\
    d+e & =f
    \end{align}
    $$
```

Comment: I didn't mention the blank line thing because the question asked about the equivalent of `<br>`, which is a line break (implemented by the two spaces), not a paragraph break. I assumed, perhaps incorrectly, that Timo knew about paragraph breaks but not about line breaks. But of course you're right that (probably literally) 99.9% of the time a paragraph break, not a line break, is the right thing to use.

Comment: Note that the `$$` in your `$$\begin{align}...\end{align}$$` are superfluous. The system recognizes what `\begin{align}...\end{align}` means.

Comment: @Kyle I know. But one step at a time.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a little surprised you've been around for months without having noticed that StackExchange doesn't use LaTeX ;-) Posts here are composed in a variant of [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax), and as dmckee pointed out in a comment there is an [editing help page](https://physics.stackexchange.com/editing-help) that explains most features of Markdown syntax, or the particular variant SE uses. Right at the [top of the page](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#linebreaks) is

> End a line with two spaces to add a `<br/>` linebreak

Comment: Whilst on the topic of formatting text, is there any way I can 'justify' my text (in the text alignment sense) to make it look like a neat block? I hate it when the edges are uneven :)

Comment: @JamalS no, Markdown doesn't do text justification. You could use a custom stylesheet though.

Comment: Do you think SE would entertain that feature request? It's something that's been irking me.

Comment: @JamalS you can certainly ask on [meta.SE] - maybe someone already has - but I doubt it would get implemented. I don't think there are many people who care about justification. And it is simple (in a way) to do yourself; it's just a matter of adding `div.post-text {text-align: justify}` to a custom stylesheet, although how exactly you do that depends on your browser.